# In c++ win, run console app as hidden window before login and then after login tray icon to unhide

Tags: winapi

Let’s say I have a tcp/ip server application that I wrote in win32 c++ as a console application.

Now I want this application to run automatically in the background as soon as the system finishes booting with the console window hidden, and not requiring the user to login to his account.  Additionally I would like a small icon to appear in the users tray after the user login that the user can use to hide and unhide the console application started before login.

How would I do this in windows 10/11?  Or do you have any ideas how to approximate this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

To run an app in the background, especially outside of a user session, you need to make it run as a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services).  But then it couldn't have a console anymore.

Due to security concerns, from Windows Vista onward, a service can't interact with user sessions (read up about [Session 0 Isolation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361)), and so cannot directly display its own tray icon. You would need to instead implement the tray icon in a separate non-service process that is started whenever a user logs in (either using the Registry's [`Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) keys, or by having the service [monitor `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex) for user logins and then call [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) when detected).

If you want the user to see a UI to interact with the service, you would have to create your own UI for that purpose. The service process would not have a UI of its own, but a UI process (whether that is the tray icon process itself, or another process it spawns upon user command) can use an IPC mechanism of your choosing, such as a named pipe or socket, to communicate with the service as needed - to retrieve status for display, to invoke tasks in the service, etc.

Comment: thanks.  Maybe instead I can use the client console app in the system tray and have it connect to the server app running as a service